# Chef colored output in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, chef-infra, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline, chefspec

I'm running unit tests in Jenkins with chef.

`chef exec rake unit`

Everything is working correctly except there is not any colored output.

I have enabled `AnsiColor Plugin` Jenkins plugin and am getting colored output for non chef tests just fine.

Are there additional steps in order to get chef's output colored in Jenkins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can force this on the RSpec command line with `--color`. Or because you're wrapping that in a Rake command, add it in your Rake task. (or in a `.rspecrc` file)